# Error Installing soapui-eclipse-plugin

Tags: eclipse, soapui

Trying to install soapui-eclipse-plugin and I am getting the below error in Eclipse:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://www.soapui.org/eclipse/update/plugins/com.eviware.soapui.eclipse_4.0.1.jar.
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 89807372; received: 257284
```

Could someone advise, what we can be done to resolve this issue, please.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware, but the SoapUI-Eclipse plugin was (quietly) abandoned several years back.

Answer (score 0):

Subsequently on a long trial and error, I’ve found a solution for my above concern:

Resolution:
Downgraded the JAVA Compiler Version from 1.8 to 1.7, I’ve successfully installed soapui-eclipse-plugin now..